# Independence Testing for Discrete Random Variable

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, independence, goodness-of-fit

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are two discrete random variable take values on $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ with their iid observation $\{ X_i\}_{i = 1}^n$ and $\{ Y_i\}_{i = 1}^n$. If both $\mathcal{X}$ and $\mathcal{Y}$ are finite, we can just use chi-square test to testing whether $X \perp Y$, see [Pearson's chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test)
.

Now, if we suppose $\mathcal{X}$ or $\mathcal{Y}$ is infinity, for example, we assume that $\mathcal{X} = \mathcal{Y} = \{ 1,2, \ldots, \} = \mathbb{N}$. How can we construct a consistent test for testing whether $X \perp Y$? I spend two day to search for some relevant literature, but it has been proved to be futile.

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In a finite sample you will observe only a finite number of categories. You can consider all the rest as a single category with zero observations and apply the same test

Comment: @J.Delaney Thank you! But I think this approach may not a consistent test. For example, we can always construct $X$ and $Y$ on $(\mathbb{N}, \sigma\langle \mathbb{N}\rangle, \mathrm{P})$ such that $X \perp Y$ on $\sigma\langle \{ 1, \ldots, n\} \rangle$ but $X(n + 1) = Y(n + 1)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: That doesn't imply inconsistency. For any fixed $n$ in your example you can find some large enough sample size such that you will observe the correlated samples and reject the null hypothesis with probability that approaches 1.

Comment: @J.Delaney Thanks! But in my personal opinion, this test still may not be consistent: as the sample size $n \rightarrow \infty$, the degree of freedom of the chi-square test statistic will also go to infinity.